# android youtubeapi open play list inside app

Tags: android, api, youtube, playlist

i'm noob using the youtubeapi for android, i've setup and i've launched the demo app with success, but seeing the demo examples it seems that when you select a play list, the app launch an Intent that goest outside the app, using the network explorer. I'd like to load a play list inside my app, is it possible?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I had done similar kind of app in the past. Using youtubeapi i played the video inside my app, but play store suspended the app replied-- `"After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads, monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed on Google Play."`

Be careful.

Comment: Oops, it could be a problem, surely. Maybe you had inapp items or ads wih Admob?

Comment: ya i used admob, that may be the problem.

Comment: Yes...well after reading a bit more about this topic, it seems that they could suspend your account only by playing copyrighted videos :(... The only solution i see it could be publishing through another store more lenient like Amazon, Samsung...

Comment: ok. thanks for your valuable information. will try it on amazon. will amazon accept admob?

Comment: Yes, of course, in fact i have some apps published in Amazon Market, Samsung, Mobango, Opera, AndroidPIT...all of them allow Admob or whatever ad network you desire